# Stop unloading the Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have one Linux kernel module which is based on platform driver.
I have implemented `probe()` and `remove()` methods there.

```
struct platform_driver {
    int (*probe)(struct platform_device *);
    int (*remove)(struct platform_device *);
}
```

Now when user perform `rmmod <myModule>` then
`remove()` method is being called. here I perform some condition check and came to know that user should not perform `rmmod` here. Here I do not want to perform any clean up and make this rmmod fail.

I have tried returning `-1` or `-EBUSY` in `remove()` but still after `rmmod <myModule>` it get unloaded and does not show in `lsmod`'s output.

Is there any way to stop unloading of my module in `remove()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot *cancel* (or *stop*) module unloading, already initiated by `rmmod` (or by other means). But it is possible to **prevent** module unloading by calling `try_module_get` on it:

```
// Before your module enters into the state, when its unloading is not desirable.

// Prevent unloading of the module
if(!try_module_get(THIS_MODULE)) {
  <failed to prevent module unloading>
}

<....> // This code will be protected from the module's unloading

// Allow the module to be unloaded again
module_put(THIS_MODULE);
```

While (successful) call to `try_module_get` is in effect, `rmmod` immediately rejects module unloading without executing any module's code.

I am not sure whether `try_module_get` would succeed being called from the `module_init` function, and calling it from `module_exit` function would definitely fail. But in all other places this call should succeed.

As for `module_put` call, one doesn't need to perform it from the same function which calls `try_module_get`. You could to not call `module_put` at all, but this should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Semi dirty hack. The proper way is to define it as built-in (using `bool` in *Kconfig*) and supply `.suppress_bind_attribute` (or how is it called?).

Comment: @0andriy: It could be your approach is preferred for prevent a module from unloading **forever**, but call to `try_module_get` is definitely a proper way for prevent a module from unloading **for some time**.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks man. This is perfectly what i needed